# Create string based on bitfield

Tags: python, bit-fields

I am using a 5-bit bitfield to track status of an alarm system in a python script. For example, 0 in the MSB indicates "Not Armed", while 1 in the MSB indicates "Armed", etc.  This enables XOR on the previous state and current state to yield quickly which bits have changed:

```
previous = 0b11001
current =  0b10011
delta = current ^ previous   # delta = 0b01010
```

The next step in my code is to generate a string that describes what changed, based on `delta`. There are 10 possible states with descriptions. I'm wondering about the best way to create this string. What I have below works, but seems clunky:

```
statusKey = {
         0: ' * Disarmed',
        10: ' * No Alarm',
        20: ' * No Fire',
        30: ' * No Check',
        40: ' * No AC',
         1: ' * Armed',
        11: ' * Alarm',
        21: ' * Fire',
        31: ' * Check',
        41: ' * AC'
         }

alert = ''
for i in range (5):
    if (0b10000 & (delta << i)):
         alert = ''.join((alert,statusKey[(10*i) + (0b01 & (current >> (4-i)))]))

#alert = 'No Alarm * Check'
```

Is there a better way to structure the data in `statusKey` ? 
And is there a better way to generate the `alert` string based on that structure?

Comment: you could use `numpy.bitwise_and` over a column but it's a little excessive for so little data.  Your method isn't terrible.

Comment: @stevedc this question might be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) if you want to ask over there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use as little bitwise math operators as possible because it makes your code very unreadable. A simple list comprehension is all you really need. Also, you want your bit status data structure to be *self-descriptive*. Someone reading it for the first time should immediately understand the logic.

```
bit_status = {
    0: ("Disarmed", "Armed"),
    1: ("No Alarm", "Alarm"),
    2: ("No Fire", "Fire"),
    3: ("No Check", "Check"),
    4: ("No AC", "AC")
}

previous = 0b11001
current =  0b10011

current_bits = [current >> i & 1 for i in reversed(range(5))]
delta_bits = [(current ^ previous) >> i & 1 for i in reversed(range(5))]

status = [bit_status[index][current_bits[index]] 
    for index, delta_bit in enumerate(delta_bits) if delta_bit == 1]

print(" * ".join(status))
# No Alarm * Check
```